# Is it possible for Rails to close a client / browser connection but continue to execute in the background?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a relatively long task that must run in a controller action but does not need be completed before the view is rendered. How can I close the browser connection but continue the running the task? This seems like a common thing to do but I can find anything on SO or Google on how to do it.

TIA!

**EDIT:**

Would like to do the Rails equivalent of the following PHP code:

```
$contentLength = ob_get_length();

// these headers tell the browser to close the connection   
// once all content has been transmitted  
header("Content-Length: $contentLength");  
header('Connection: close'); 

// flush all output
ob_end_flush();
ob_flush();
flush();

// Finish the task.
```

Answer (score 1):

In rails 3 do

```
class MyController < ApplicationController
   def index
     self.response_body = lambda do |response,output|
        5.times do |i| 
           response.write i
           sleep(2)
        end

     end
   end   
end
```

However you need fix a bug of rails 3

they executes 2 times the same lambda

include one file in config/initializers/rack_patch.rb

```
class Rack::Response
  def close
    @body.close if @body.respond_to?(:close)
  end
end
```

Comment: I have not tried your example yet but how does `close` get called?

Answer (score 0):

Use the [delayed_job](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job) gem for this. It allows you to specify background tasks to be run.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [resque](https://github.com/defunkt/resque) gem too

Answer (score 0):

Two solutions have been pointed out so far. Those and others are listed in the Ruby Toolbox, here: http://ruby-toolbox.com/categories/queueing.html